# Change function of power button

Tags: windows-7

I have a pc (self built desktop) and I would like to change the function of the power button.

I want to do this, because the button is pretty big, and I accedently hit it some times.

If I could make it go in sleep mode on a tap and shutdown if you hold it in 5 seconds it could be nice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change what pressing the power button does directly in windows. This is not something you can change in the bios actually.

Do note, holding the power button for 5 seconds is called a hardware shutdown. It instantly shuts down the power as if the cable is unplugged. This cannot be overridden and should not be used to end a windows session unless windows is not responsive and its your only option.

Now, in order to change what the powerbutton does, follow these steps:

1. Right click on an empty part of your desktop
2. Choose `Personalize`
3. At the bottom riht, click `Screen Saver`
4. At the bottom, click `Change power settings`
5. At the left, click `Choose what the power buttons do`
6. Either change to `sleep` or `do nothing` depending on your preferences.

You can always use the start menu to sleep and shutdown. The reason why do nothing might be preferred, is because you seem to accidentally hit it. Sleeping can be as irritating as shutting down when it comes to accidentally hitting it, so a `do nothing` might be preferred.

It is even possible to add buttons in the startmenu, taskbar or desktop that you can use to put the computer to sleep or to shutdown windows, by using the shutdown command.

Comment: Thank you. Norma I also use the shutdown button in the windows start menu. The 5 seconds thing is only if it does freeze. Thanks again.